# Sort json object by key value using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I am trying to sort json object by key, but the keys sometimes contain an array therefore it sort data incorrectly. the problem with my function : it dosen't compare array's index I just want to get my data sorted by the full key.

Below the wrong output result.

```js
const byKey = o =>
 Object.keys(o)
   .sort()
   .reduce((r, k) => ((r[k] = o[k]), r), {});
```

**Wrong** output result

```
{
  "admin.name":"Okdaro fripi:",
  "amazon.token":"kqjndkJQNDjkmdnJKQDNKmjdqnmjdnQKMD",
  "data.content":"ABCD",
  "dimitro.job":"create",
  "person.account.email[0].card[0]":"VISA",
  "person.account.email[0].firstname":"George Blaksar",
  "person.account.email[0].org":"gmail",
  "person.account.email[10].card[0]":"yalla",
  "person.account.email[10].firstname":"qabte",
  "person.account.email[10].org":"amazon",
  "person.account.email[1].card[0]":"Master card",
  "person.account.email[1].firstname":"balbi",
  "person.account.email[1].org":"yahoo",
  "person.account.email[2].card[0]":"payoneer",
  "person.account.email[2].firstname":"pinaro",
  "person.account.email[2].org":"facebook",
...
  "person.account.email[9].card[0]":"yalla",
  "person.account.email[9].firstname":"qabte",
  "person.account.email[9].org":"amazon",
  "zend.port":99
}
```

Below what I want to get

```
{
 "admin.name": "Okdaro fripi:",
 "amazon.token": "kqjndkJQNDjkmdnJKQDNKmjdqnmjdnQKMD",
 "data.content": "ABCD",
 "dimitro.job": "create",
 "person.account.email[0].card[0]": "VISA",
 "person.account.email[0].firstname": "George Blaksar",
 "person.account.email[0].org": "gmail",
 "person.account.email[1].card[0]": "Master card",
 "person.account.email[1].firstname": "balbi",
 "person.account.email[1].org": "yahoo",
 "person.account.email[2].card[0]": "payoneer",
 "person.account.email[2].firstname": "pinaro",
 "person.account.email[2].org": "facebook",
 "person.account.email[3].card[0]": "aws",
 "person.account.email[3].firstname": "zartb",
 "person.account.email[3].org": "amazon",
 "person.account.email[4].card[0]": "Master card 4",
 "person.account.email[4].firstname": "blinago ",
 "person.account.email[4].org": "yahoo",
 "person.account.email[5].card[0]": "lbl",
 "person.account.email[5].firstname": "tarficana",
 "person.account.email[5].org": "netflix",
 "person.account.email[6].card[0]": "yalla",
 "person.account.email[6].firstname": "qabte",
 "person.account.email[6].org": "amazon",
 "person.account.email[7].card[0]": "Master card 4",
 "person.account.email[7].firstname": "blinago ",
 "person.account.email[7].org": "yahoo",
 "person.account.email[8].card[0]": "lbl",
 "person.account.email[8].firstname": "tarficana",
 "person.account.email[8].org": "netflix",
 "person.account.email[9].card[0]": "yalla",
 "person.account.email[9].firstname": "qabte",
 "person.account.email[9].org": "amazon",
  "person.account.email[10].card[0]": "yalla",
 "person.account.email[10].firstname": "qabte",
 "person.account.email[10].org": "amazon",
 "zend.port": 99
}
```

Comment: Objects don't have order.  Are you looking to create an ordered array of keys, maybe?

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have updated my question by adding what I want to get as a result

Comment: Your desired result is still an object, so your question is a non-starter unless you are looking to order a data type that is actually order-able.

Comment: Let me go in another direction. What are you doing which is requiring this to be sorted?

Comment: @LearningEveryDay , my goal is just to sort them out with the full key

Answer (score 0):

You could order the keys with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) and using *options* which sorts by groups of the string.

```js
const
    object = {
        "admin.name": "Okdaro fripi:",
        "amazon.token": "kqjndkJQNDjkmdnJKQDNKmjdqnmjdnQKMD",
        "data.content": "ABCD",
        "dimitro.job": "create",
        "person.account.email[0].card[0]": "VISA",
        "person.account.email[0].firstname": "George Blaksar",
        "person.account.email[0].org": "gmail",
        "person.account.email[10].card[0]": "yalla",
        "person.account.email[10].firstname": "qabte",
        "person.account.email[10].org": "amazon",
        "person.account.email[1].card[0]": "Master card",
        "person.account.email[1].firstname": "balbi",
        "person.account.email[1].org": "yahoo",
        "person.account.email[2].card[0]": "payoneer",
        "person.account.email[2].firstname": "pinaro",
        "person.account.email[2].org": "facebook",
        "person.account.email[9].card[0]": "yalla",
        "person.account.email[9].firstname": "qabte",
        "person.account.email[9].org": "amazon",
        "zend.port": 99
    };

console.log(Object.fromEntries(Object
    .entries(object)
    .sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' })))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Awesome that's what i want, but why you removed the value of keys !! I need all the line , that means key and it's value

Comment: you could take the entries of the object and sort by index zero.

Comment: I am beginner with javascript, could you please update your answer by adding that please . thanks !

Comment: your updated function return an object of arrays , but I want them as a full json object with key and value